# Extracting part of a file path

Tags: regex, scala

Using Scala, I am trying to extract a value from a path e.g.

```
val path = hdfs://aloha/data/8907yhb/folders/folder=2319/
```

What regex can I use for [extracting part]

I have tried it at https://regexr.com/

[[image: I've tried different expressions]]

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvgVX.png)

```
"=[0-9]*"
```

I didn't get exactly what I expected.

The best result I got:

```
=2319
```

but I need to get only

```
2319
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use look behind `(?<=...)` pattern.

```
(?<==)[0-9]* // matches zero or more digits but only if they follow the '=' sign.
```

Example:

```
scala> "(?<==)[0-9]*".r.findAllIn("hdfs://aloha/data/8907yhb/folders/folder=2319/").toList

List(2319)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a capture group, and repeat matching the digits 1 or more times to prevent empty matches:

```
=([0-9]+)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Tpa4B8/1) and a [Scala demo](https://ideone.com/auPTNf).

For example:

```
val path = "hdfs://aloha/data/8907yhb/folders/folder=2319/"
val pattern = "=([0-9]+)".r

val result = pattern.findFirstMatchIn(path) match {
  case Some(v) => v.group(1)
  case _ => "No match"
}

println(result)
```

Or with `\d` to match a digit:

```
val pattern = "=(\\d+)".r
```

Output

```
2319
```